# Connecting Java EE application with Sql Server in virtual box

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, jdbc, java-ee-6, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu installed on my laptop, and I'm developing a web application with java, using eclipse, and I want to connect, with sql server. To do this I have installed sql server 2012 in my virtual machine(Virtual box).
I have installed windows 7. I'm using Bridged Adapter setting, to receive ip from dhcp.
I have tested connection with ping command and is running successful, but when I run my application I have this error: Unknown server host name 'PEACH-PC'
the PEACH-PC is the

Comment: Sorry, about text format. Peach-PC is virtual machine host name.

Comment: What are the connection properties like?

Answer (score 2):

have you added Peach-PC variable in the etc/hosts file? that may be the case. If not add the ip and the variable there.